# .zip file gets corrupted when sent with gmail api and compressed with zlib

Tags: python, gmail-api, mime-types, zlib, mime

I am using Python 3.7 and compressing a `.csv` file using python's `zipfile` and `zlib`.

```
import zipfile

filename = "report.csv"

zip_filename = f"{filename[:-4]}.zip"
with zipfile.ZipFile(zip_filename, "w", compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip:
    zip.write(filename)
```

The zip file is then attached to an email, I have some logic to determine its MIME type (I have checked that it correctly determines that it's `application/zip`):

```
def _make_attachment_part(self, filename: str) -> MIMEBase:
    content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
    if content_type is None or encoding is not None:
        content_type = "application/octet-stream"

    main_type, sub_type = content_type.split("/", 1)
    msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        msg.set_payload(f.read())

    base_filename = os.path.basename(filename)
    msg.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename=base_filename)

    return msg
```

Then, the subject, recipients, cc, attachments etc. are set for the `message` which is of the `MIMEMultipart` type. Then, I use `base64` for encoding and send it through.

```
raw_message = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()
```

I receive my attachment named correctly and of the expected size, however, when I try to use `unzip file.zip`, I get the following error:

```
error [file.zip]:  missing 5 bytes in zipfile
```

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong? As a matter of fact, the email is sent from Ubuntu machine, whereas I'm trying to open the received file on MacOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As defined in the [rfc1341](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/5_Content-Transfer-Encoding.html):

> An encoding type of 7BIT requires that the body is already in a seven-bit mail- ready representation. This is the default value -- that is, "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7BIT" is assumed if the Content-Transfer-Encoding header field is not present.

In your case, in the `_make_attachment_part` function, you are setting the payload to your `MIMEBase` object, but you are not specifying the Content-Transfer-Encoding.

I suggest that you encode your payload as Base64. You can do it as follows:

1. Import the `encoders` module

```py
from email import encoders
```

2. Inside your `_make_attachment_part` function, encode your payload using the `encoders` module.

```py
def _make_attachment_part(self, filename: str) -> MIMEBase:
    content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(filename)
    if content_type is None or encoding is not None:
        content_type = "application/octet-stream"

    main_type, sub_type = content_type.split("/", 1)
    msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
        msg.set_payload(f.read())

    encoders.encode_base64(msg) # NEW

    base_filename = os.path.basename(filename)
    msg.add_header("Content-Disposition", "attachment", filename=base_filename)

    return msg
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! This indeed solves the problem!