# Using python 3 and Gmail API to send emails with attachments, I end up with either corrupted files or ConnectionAbortedError

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64, gmail-api

I am using the Gmail API in Python 3 to send emails with attachments, based on their example code

I've got the following to create the message:

```
def create_message_with_attachment(
    sender, to, subject, message_text, files):
  """Create a message for an email.

  Args:
    sender: Email address of the sender.
    to: Email address of the receiver.
    subject: The subject of the email message.
    message_text: The text of the email message.
    file: The path to the file to be attached.

  Returns:
    An object containing a base64url encoded email object.
  """
  message = MIMEMultipart()
  message['to'] = to
  message['from'] = sender
  message['subject'] = subject

  msg = MIMEText(message_text)
  message.attach(msg)

  for file in files:

    content_type, encoding = mimetypes.guess_type(file)

    if content_type is None or encoding is not None:
      content_type = 'application/octet-stream'
    main_type, sub_type = content_type.split('/', 1)
    if main_type == 'text':
      fp = open(file, 'rb')
      msg = MIMEText(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
      fp.close()
    elif main_type == 'image':
      fp = open(file, 'rb')
      msg = MIMEImage(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
      fp.close()
    elif main_type == 'audio':
      fp = open(file, 'rb')
      msg = MIMEAudio(fp.read(), _subtype=sub_type)
      fp.close()
    else:
      fp = open(file, 'rb')
      msg = MIMEBase(main_type, sub_type)
      msg.set_payload(fp.read())
      fp.close()
    filename = os.path.basename(file)
    msg.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename=filename)
    message.attach(msg)

  raw = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())
  raw = raw.decode()
  body = {'raw': raw}
  return body
```

And the following to send:

```
def send_message(service, user_id, message):
    """Send an email message.

  Args:
    service: Authorized Gmail API service instance.
    user_id: User's email address. The special value "me"
    can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
    message: Message to be sent.

  Returns:
    Sent Message.
    """
    try:
        message = (service.users().messages().send(userId=user_id, body=message).execute())
        print ('Sent! Message Id: %s' % message['id'])
        return message
    except httplib2.HttpLib2Error as error:
        return None
        print ('An error occurred: %s' % error)
```

When I send a mail created like this (I need to send pdf's, but tried with a zip as well with the same results) it works but the files are corrupted. I'm assuming this happens during the base64 encoding.

I saw in [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58561812/zip-file-gets-corrupted-when-sent-with-gmail-api-and-compressed-with-zlib) that adding `encoders.encode_base64(msg)` (just above/below `filename = os.path.basename(file)` in my case) solves the issue, however when I add that line I get:
`ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine`

Apparently it does that when it doesn't like a file?

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

### The confusion with the correct encoding is due to the change from Python 2 to Python 3

The encoding procedure described in the [Google documentation for sending emails](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending) is based on Python 2. I assume you are using Python 3.

To adapt the guide to the new Python version two modifications need to be implemented.

1. Modify `return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}`
   to `return {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode()}`. You have done this already.
2. After `msg.set_payload(contents)` request you need to add an **additional line** `encoders.encode_base64(msg)`. This is what you were missing.

> Now that you added it, mind that `encoders` is a module of the package `email`. If not already
>   done, you need to add to your code  `from email import encoders`

Comment: Thanks :) I have imported `encoders` - as mentioned though when I add the line `encoders.encode_base64(msg)` I get "ConnectionAbortedError: [WinError 10053] An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine." This is what I can't figure out, as it seems to work for other people. I have even tried turning off antivirus and firewall just in case that was causing some issue, but still getting the same error :(

Comment: Sounds like a problem with your configuration / network settings. Did you try it on a different device? Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51562067/connectionabortederror-winerror-10053-an-established-connection-was-aborted-b) is helpful?